# Load HTML/PHP into div, iframe alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an html/php page which I want to place into a div, but i'd prefer not to use an iframe. The page relies on a get request to work. Is there any purpose built framework/solution for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `$.load` https://api.jquery.com/load/

Though I wouldn't guarantee the page would look great, as the host page's styles might break the styles of the loaded page (and vice versa). Plus, if you happen to select a certain part of the page (`$.load` allows you to), anything other than the selection will be stripped out - including scripts, which won't be executed too.